# Carrierwave not saving thumbnail in db

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, image, carrierwave

if i uploade a image, the original version and the thumb version is created but the thumb version is not saved in the database.

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end


# encoding: utf-8

class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
   version :thumb do
     process :resize_to_limit => [50, 50]
   end   
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't save it in the database. Rather, you'll see a new thumbnail version in your upload directory. You can call this version by referencing to that version when calling the image field.

ie

`<%= image_tag @image.image(:thumb).url %>`

Comment: so i dont need to save it into a column 'thumb' ?

Comment: You can look at http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads which has a good example of what you're doing.